# xamarin Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: Activity{x} did not call through to super.onStart()

Tags: c#, xamarin

I get this error for the code shown below and don't know why.
my code is:

```js
 protected override void OnStart()
        {            
            if (WCHSBMobileApplication.Current.SuperBillObject == null)
            {
                AddSuperBill();
            }
            else
            {
                EditSuperBill();
            }
        }
```

what can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exception message says it all:

You removed this line:

```
base.OnStart();
```

You need to add it back:

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
    base.OnStart();

    if (WCHSBMobileApplication.Current.SuperBillObject == null)
    {
        AddSuperBill();
    }
    else
    {
        EditSuperBill();
    }
}
```